# Label not showing value of timer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a timer loop that executes a basic countdown and it prints the value to the console. I'm trying to have that value set to a text value of a label. Even though the Xcode console shows the correct countdown of the timer value, the label in the application still shows 0. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    var timerCount = 7
    var timerRunning = false
    var timer = NSTimer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.timerCount = 7

       self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func Counting(){

        timerCount = 7

        do {

            println(timerCount)
            timerRunning = true
            --timerCount
            timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
            println(timerCount)

        } while timerCount > 0

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method Counting() is wrong.

Every second you are launching the counting method and within that method you have a loop which updates the timerLabel.text, but the UI is not updated until the  Counting() finishes...that's why is always showing 0. You need just to decrease the counting every second and update the label.

I think this is what you need:

```
func Counting(){

  if timerCount == 0
  {
    timerCount = 7 // or self.timer.invalidate() in case you want to  stop it
  }        
  else
  {
     timerCount--;
     timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
     println(timerCount)
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That worked. Thanks! What I don't understand though is why in my original code was the label.text = "" getting passed over within the loop? I stepped through my code with breakpoints and it went to that line and didn't update the text. Why would it perform the other lines while the condition was true?

Comment: look this example:

func example() {     timerLabel.text = "7";  timerLabel.text = "6" ;   timerLabel.text = "5";  timerLabel.text = "4" ;   timerLabel.text = "3";  timerLabel.text = "2" ;   timerLabel.text = "1" ; timerLabel.text = "0" ; }

What are you going to see in the UI when you execute this function is just  timerLabel.text = "0".  Think that the UI is updated every time the function ends. So the label at the end of that functions is equal to "0".  Hence ,the UI is showing you just "0".